# Strange top space with tab bar on iOS7

Tags: ios7, tabbar

I have a tabBarController, each viewController of the tabBarController has a webview to load web pages.

When the app start, there's an unexpected white space on top of the webview, the space's size is approximately (screen width * status bar height), the screenshot like this:
[image]

But if I click another tab, then go back to this tab, the white space is gone.

This bug is just in iOS7, Theres's no unexpected space in iOS8.
And This bug just exists in device, simulator hasn't this bug.

Please give some advice how to fix this bug.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the webview's `contentInsets`. Try setting that manually in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @AaronBrager Thank you so much. Yes, In the parent class there is a method, -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews. It uses self.topLayoutGuide.length, this value is 20 when app starts, but when switches between tabs the value is 0. So the 20 is the reason causes the white space bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with the webview's `contentInsets`. Try setting that manually in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.